# How do I access an Entry by a specific attribute in Craft CMS?

Tags: php, craftcms

I am looking for a programatic way to access an entry by an attribute in PHP, using Craft CMS 3.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Craft::$app->getEntries()->getEntryById('1234');
```

`getEntryById()` seems to be the only method available off of `getEntries()` ...

What I would like to do (in pseudo code):

```
Craft::$app->getEntries()->getEntryByAttribute('ItemNumber', '1234');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query an Entry by field value like this:

```
\craft\elements\Entry::find()->section('mySection')->where(['field_myFieldHandle' => $myValue])->one();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. By the way, what is the difference between `Craft::$app->getEntries()` and `\craft\elements\Entry::find()`? Is one preferential over another?